# MySQL Query to Display Organized by Date

Tags: mysql, query, eav, report-builder

I'm good with basic types of queries but this has me stumped. I have the table schema listed below, I need display the results in a table, with each row displaying the available results for a given date. I've also drawn out the required table layout below. I hope this is clear enough. Is there a query I could use to fetch these results at once? Currently, I'm queries each date and then stitching the results together which is inefficient.

**Fields Table Schema**

`+--------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type           | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                 | varbinary(255) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| value              | varchar(255)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| form_submission_id | varbinary(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| form_field_id      | varbinary(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| created_at         | timestamp      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| updated_at         | timestamp      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| deleted_at         | timestamp      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+--------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+`

**Required Query Results**

`+--------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+
| created_at   | form_field_id | form_field_id | form_field_id 3 |
+--------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+
| Apr 14, 2019 | value         | value         | value           |
+--------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+
| Apr 13, 2019 | value         | value         | value           |
+--------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+
| Apr 12, 2019 | value         | value         | value           |
+--------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+
| Apr 11, 2019 | value         | value         | value           |
+--------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+
| Apr 10, 2019 | value         | value         | value           |
+--------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+`

Comment: Are the form_field_id values known ahead of the query? Where there is more than onve value per day, which do you want? Looking pivot tables. I assume you know how to aggregate on created_at day on display its date? What MySQL version?

Comment: @danblack I will have an array of form_field_id ahead of time. Never more than value per day. Mysql V8.0.15

Comment: It is referred to as "pivot". MySQL have no this type of query. I'd recommend to perform this transformation on the client side using its reporting subsystem. *Fields Table Schema* Replace it with table's `CREATE TABLE`. *Required Query Results* Replace it with sample data (INSERT INTO) and the result on THAT data. Alternatively to evereything above - create a fiddle.

Comment: Welcome to the painful coding behind Entity-Attribute-Value schema.  See the tag I added.